# Raspberry Pi 2 B Tkinter performance problem

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi2

I am trying to write a simple python program for a Rasperry Pi 2 Model B. When finished it should be able to get a few values via uart and display one out of 200 images based on that.
Additionally, it will show a video and a few static images. For that, I use Tkinter and Tkvideo.
But now I run in to serious performance problems. I thought this is a simple Project and would work. But the Raspberry has trouble, even if I only start VS Code on it, and the text input has a delay of over a second.

As OS, I use ([Debian version: 11 (bullseye)](https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/operating-systems/)), the python version is 3.9

I reduced the Code, so it only opens a window and plays the one video:
Even if I only show the video, it renders in ca. 1-2 fps.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkvideo import tkvideo
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class App():
    def __init__(self):
       self.timeStartMS = int(round(time.time() * 1000))

       self.root = Tk()
       self.root.geometry("1280x800")

       label3 = Label(self.root, width=200, height=800, borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
       label3.place(x=420,y=0)
       label3v = Label(label3)
       label3v.place(x=200,y=100)

       player = tkvideo("Video/testVideo.mp4", label3v ,loop=1)
       player.play()
       self.root.after(self.msPerFrame, self.update)
    
       self.root.mainloop()

app = App()
```

Is a Raspberry Pi 2 B simply not strong enough for this, or what else could I do to make it work?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: first you could check hardware specification (especially CPU) - Wikipedia: [Raspberry PI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi). Next you can try to find comparitions with other CPUs. Wikipedia: [Raspberry Pi - Performance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi#Performance), other portal(s): [Benchmarking the Raspberry Pi 4](https://community.element14.com/products/raspberry-pi/w/documents/4319/benchmarking-the-raspberry-pi-4-model-b)

Comment: as for me it is not strong enough for this. I use it only as server with text mode. As I remeber sometimes it had problem even in Standard windows - like web browser.

Comment: you could also ask on similar page for [Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) or on [Raspberry Pi Forums](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/). Maybe they will have better experience.